# Solve the equation $1-x+x^{2}-x^{3}+x^{4}=y^{4}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am working on the following exercise. Solve the equation $1-x+x^{2}-x^{3}+x^{4}=y^{4}$ in $\mathbb{Z}$.

I have a couple of ideas for going about this exercise.

$1)$ By moving $1$ to the other side of the equation we obtain:

$y^4-1=x^4-x^3+x^2-x \rightarrow (y^2-1)(y^2+1)=x(x-1)(x^2+1)$.

The LHS gives two consecutive integers I am able to see, but other than that I am stuck and not sure where to go from here.

$2)$ We notice that $1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4=\Phi_{10}(x)=y^4$.

We now have that $\Phi_{10}(x) \geq 0$ since $y=\pm \sqrt[4]{1-x+x^2-x^3+x^4}$.

In this case, with some computation, $x={0,1}$ are the only possibilities that will force $y \in \mathbb{Z}$. From there, I use induction to show that $x \geq 2$ and $x \leq -1$ do not yield a perfect fourth.

In either case, I keep running into some issues. If someone could please other a hint to help me continue through this exercise, that would be very helpful. Thank you.

***Update***:

Hello, my progress on the following problem is as follows:

Suppose that $x=y$, then we get $y^3-y^2+y-1=0 \rightarrow y=1, \pm i$. Thus we get two solutions $(x,y)={(1,1),(1,-1)}$, the $y=-1$ since $y^4$ was in the original equation.

Next, using @Batominovski hint we can write:

$(2x^2-x)^2 < (x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1) < 4(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1) \leq (2x^2-x+2)^2 \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ which is true for $x=0$.

Since the multiplication of a constant (in this case $k=4$) does not affect a solution from existing, we have that $x=0$ is a solution, consequently we find two more solutions are $(x,y)=(0,1),(0,-1)$.

Comment: From the description of your approach (2), I think it would work (see e.g., a related [problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1829370/find-the-integer-x-such-x6x5x4x3x2x1-y3/1831223#1831223)).  What is the exact difficulty you had there?  Btw they are special cases of [Nagell-Ljunggren equation](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/206645/on-a-result-attributed-to-w-ljunggren-and-t-nagell).

Comment: Note that $y^4-1=(y-1)(y+1)(y^2+1)$. Not sure if that is useful.

Comment: @Wiley For showing $x \geq 2$ does not yield a perfect fourth inductively I have that

$P(k+1)=k^4+3k^3+4k^2+2k+1=(k^4-k^3+k^2-k+1)+4k^3+3k^2+3k$

where $P(k)=k^4-k^3+k^2-k+1$ is not a perfect fourth.

From this point, I was going to have another (mini) inductive proof for showing

$4k^3 +3k^2+3k$ is not a perfect fourth. In the second (mini) inductive proof I would also have the base case, true for all $x \geq 2$. I don't really see a more efficient way for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: note that for $x$ big enough the following holds:
$$(x-1)^4 < x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1 < x^4.$$
Similarly, for $x$ small enough we have
$$(x-1)^4 > x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1 > x^4.$$
Therefore you are left with a finite number of possible values of $x$.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**  Note that
$$\left(2x^2-x\right)^2<4\left(x^4-x^3+x^2-x+1\right)\leq\left(2x^2-x+2\right)^2$$
for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  The right-hand side becomes an equality if and only if $x=0$.

Comment: $x(x-1)(x^2+1)=y^4-1\Rightarrow (x,y)=(1,\pm 1)$ is solution (it can be seen at first sight).

Comment: @Batominovski I understand the set of inequalities however, how can we be certain that this will be the only solutions (knowing ($1,\pm1$)) is also a solution?

Answer (score 1):

One has $$1-x+x^{2}-x^{3}+x^{4}=y^{4}\iff(2x^2+1)^2=4y^4+4(x^3+x)-3$$ Notice that necessarily $y$ must be odd  and $x^3+x$ is even when $x$ is even or odd. Hence one has $$(2x^2+1)^2\equiv 4y^4-3 \pmod 8$$ The solutions of this congruence are
$$(x,y)=(x,1),(x,3),(x,5),(x,7)\text { with } x=0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7$$ we can verify that $\color{red}{(x,y)=(0,\pm1),(1\pm 1)}$ are the only solutions because for $y=1+8m,3+8m,5+8m,7+8m$ we have for $m=0$ these only solutions (*easier to verify for other candidates with $m\gt 1$making $1-x+x^{2}-x^{3}+x^{4}=\frac{x^5+1}{x+1}$*)

Comment: In your second line $(2x+1)^2 \equiv 4y^4 -3$ (mod 8). How did you come up with this equivalence modulo 8? I still cannot see that. Can you offer a hint?

Comment: Yes, Joseph. It is because of $x^3+x$ is always even (for $x$ being both odd and even).